# Trying to enable popup at index page instead of redirecting it to the create view, ASP.NET MVC 5 & Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

The popup code works just fine when I create it on the other view pages, it only throws an error on the index page, I'm having an issue with the model. I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework 6. Any guidance will be most appreciated.

This is my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<LogInTest1.Models.Credentials>
```

I want to create a popup here instead of redirecting it to the create page.

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
```

Button code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="AddData()">Click to Create &raquo;</button>
<script>
    function AddData() {
        $("#MyModal").modal();
    }
</script>
```

Popup code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                @*@model LogInTest1.Models.Credentials*@

                @*@using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <h4>Credentials</h4>
                        <hr />
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.userName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                }*@
                @*}*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Table code at index view:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.password)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.empId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.empId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.empId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, you can use an action link  like this:

`<a href="" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MyModal">Create New</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Your Index view having Model list but your popup using single model so you have to create the object to your popup model@{var createModel = new LogInTest1.Models.Credentials()} then your all poup codes should look like this @Html.LabelFor(cmodel => createModel.userName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

Comment: model@{ var createModel = new LogInTest1.Models.Credentials()} where shall i place this line of code. I get an error "; expected " where ever i place it . i added ";" after the line of code but still get an error

Comment: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected

Source Error:


Line 11: 
Line 12: <h2>Admin Panel</h2>
Line 13: model@{ var createModel = new LogInTest1.Models.Credentials()};
Line 14: @*PopUP Button*@
Line 15: <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="AddData()">Click to Create &raquo;</button>

Comment: your code should be like this no ; needed                                                                     @model IEnumerable<LogInTest1.Models.Credentials>                                    @{ var createModel = new LogInTest1.Models.Credentials()}

Comment: @model IEnumerable <LogInTest1.Models.Credentials> 
@{ var createModel = new LogInTest1.Models.Credentials();}

on the same line it was giving an error i wrote it on the next line , no error now but as soon as i enter username and password and click on the submit button the value doesn't get saved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486749/popup-not-sending-data-in-database-in-asp-net-mvc5-entity-framework   
here is the updated code popup is working but data is not being saved